# React JS : Группировка элементов объекта

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

Есть объект data.
Содержание объекта

```
data: {
 {
  type: 'credit',
  dept: 5000
 },
 {
  type: 'card',
  dept: 10000
 },
 {
  type: 'credit',
  dept: 2000
 },
 {
  type: 'credit',
  dept: 1000
 }
}
```

Нужно на React JS написать алгоритм, который сгруппирует все элементы объекта и посчитает их сумму. На выходе должно получиться так

```
data: {
 {
  type: 'credit',
  dept: 8000
 },
 {
  type: 'card',
  dept: 10000
 }
}
```

Можно реализовать на lodash.

Comment: Нужно изменить существующий объект? Или в новый записать?

Comment: Можно создать новый объект

Comment: причем тут react?

Answer (score 1):

> Есть объект data.

Нет объекта.

```js
var data = [
 {
  type: 'credit',
  dept: 5000
 },
 {
  type: 'card',
  dept: 10000
 },
 {
  type: 'credit',
  dept: 2000
 },
 {
  type: 'credit',
  dept: 1000
 }
];
var data1 = data.reduce((res, el) => {
  var el1 = res.find(i => i.type == el.type);
  if (!el1) {
    el1 = { type: el.type, dept: 0 };
    res.push(el1);
  }
  el1.dept += el.dept;
  return res;
}, []);
console.log(data1);
```

Comment: Не совсем то, что нужно. 
Результат должен быть таким, то бишь все тоже самое, но объекты внутри массива должны быть разделены

data: {
 {
  type: 'credit',
  dept: 8000
 },
 {
  type: 'card',
  dept: 10000
 }
}

Comment: Так `data` это объект.

Comment: Он возвращает массив, как я вижу. Что нужно сделать, что бы возвращал объект?

Comment: Может надо было уточнить, это все на реакте. Сейчас вылетает ошибка Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): res.find is not a function

Он не может найти функцию find?

Comment: @user207012 Какой объект? То, что написано в вопросе, - не объект, а синтаксическая ошибка. Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код.

Comment: @Igor Вы изначально стали писать var data = [ ... ]
Когда в вопросе начинается код  с объекта data: { ... } !!!

Comment: @user207012, код в вопросе содержит синтаксическую ошибку: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`